# “無法換給捐贈者” v.s. “無法還給捐贈者”

Tags: word-choice

On [this page](https://ctext.org/help-us/zh#donate), I read 無法換給捐贈者, which I think is both grammatically and semantically correct, however is difficult to be understood. Should that be replaced with 無法還給捐贈者?

> 希望各位捐贈者可以理解，捐贈的硬件最後可能將會被棄置或轉售，而無法換給捐贈者。

Update: Seems that it is really a mistake since in the [English version](https://ctext.org/help-us) the term is `return'.

> Please understand that donated equipment will eventually be disposed of and cannot be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the "exchange" of a comparable hardware from the donations as the return was the normal practice for such event, the sentence, 無法換給捐贈者, is semantically incorrect. 無法還給捐贈者 is correct, grammatically and semantically.

Answer (score 1):

無法**換**(exchang)給捐贈者 is incorrect

無法**還**(return) 給捐贈者 is correct

無法**退還**(return/send back)給捐贈者 would be more precise